# Editing Swift markup on the iPad Playgrounds app

Tags: swift-playground

It does not appear possible to edit previous markup on the iOS Swift Playgrounds app directly. The only way that I have found is to export the file into an Xcode Playground, perform the editing, then re-import it back into the iOS app. This is a bit long winded! Has anyone found a simpler method?

Running latest Swift Playgrounds app under iOS 12.2 on an iPad Pro 2018.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the markup part of a playground page can only be changed in an external editor. So your workflow
`Testing on iPad -> Editing in Xcode -> Syncing with iPad` 
is just fine.

Currently, this seems to be the philosophy behind Swift Playgrounds. 
The developer is intended to build a playground in Xcode, which the user can experience on their iPad. This includes the restriction to certain editable regions within a playground page. The user is not (yet) supposed to change major parts of the source code (including markup parts) solely on iPad.

Comment: However, JoRa, as I have experienced, Playgrounds gives the very best coding on a mobile device that I have ever experienced. So it’s a bit of a shame that we can’t fully document as well as we are able to code.